# Forces acting on a ball when its squeezed

Tags: forces, displacement

I am new to this forum. I am currently working on a project in the field of tangible user interface. I am developing a game in which a pressure sensor squeezable ball is the input controller. I am done with the game. Now I need to design a squeeze ball.

My next aim is to find out the number of sensors required, their ideal locations in the ball so that user's fingers are utilized to the maximum while playing the game & maximum forces are applied to the sensor locations.

**So I would like to find out theoretically the points where maximum forces are applied when we squeeze a ball.** Also I want to know the forces acting & displacements occurring while squeezing a ball.

Any input to this will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Anuroop

Comment: This is more of an engineering problem than a physics problem isn't it? Also you don't specify important factors like size of ball, whether ball is desk-mounted or free, whether the hand holds the ball or rests on it, size of hand, number of degrees of control needed and so on. Fortunately you have two-built-in sensor-rich appendages (AKA fists) you can use for empirical testing. Mine suggest the answer is "under the fingertips". Your Mileage May Vary.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks a lot for the reply. The ball I am using is the common smiley balls available in the market. The type of squeeze which I am interested is using the fingers & palm of the hand. I am looking for a way, theoretically, to find out the maximum pressure areas while squeezing the ball. I want to write equations & show where the maximum is being felt.